# Translate from applemac to utf8

Tags: input-encodings

Hi at all i want to translate [this](http://www.lorenzopantieri.net/LaTeX_files/TesiModerna.zip) template from applemac to utf8 how can i do?

thanks at all !

Comment: And did you try changing `\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}` to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in `Tesi.tex`?

Comment: yeah but i have some errors...

Comment: Please explicitly mention the errors; otherwise we cannot do anything.

Comment: It's simply a scheme. There's nothing in it that requires the `applemac` encoding. Just write your own thesis in the encoding you prefer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before Lion it was possible to use the soft Cyclone but now another possibility is to use textedit ( I suppose that you work with a math ). In the prefs of textedit go to Preferences and choice the item Open and save ( I have the soft in french so I don't know exactly the texts) New choices opening encoding : Occidental : mac os roman  save encoding : UTF8.

Now you can open a file with mac roman and save it with UTF8. You can re-encode Tesi.tex from applemac to UTF8.

It' s posible with textmate and with textwrangler (I suppose)

If you want to convert a lot of files, you can use the command from the terminal

```
  iconv -f MAC -t UTF8 fileMacOSRoman.tex > fileUTF8.tex
```

and then you need to change `\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}` to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in Tesi.tex

Comment: The author has translated him from apple mac to utf8 thanks to all the same!

Comment: I would like the headers like the TeXbook how can I do?

i have try to open a new question but the system says this error:

Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

It does not meet our quality standards.